# Type mismatch in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to convert character values to ASCII values in java.
Below is my code.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the string to be converted");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str =input.nextLine();
        char ch[]=str.toCharArray();//hello
        for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            char ascii[i]=ch[i];
            System.out.println((int)ascii[i]);
        }

        input.close(); 
    }
}
```

I want to get the string from the user, and store it in an array(which I a m doing it in `ch[]`) and for each element in array, I want to print its corresponding ASCII value.

But at line `char ascii[i]=ch[i];` the interpreter is telling `Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to char[]`.

Where is the problem ? as both of my character initialization are arrays, then why is it telling that its type mismatch ?

Note: I want the `ascii` variable to be stored as an array only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't assign a `char` to a `char` array.

Change

```
    for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        char ascii[i]=ch[i];
        System.out.println((int)ascii[i]);
    }
```

to

```
    for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        char ascii = ch[i];
        System.out.println((int)ascii);
    }
```

EDIT:

If you wish to store the output in an array, you should declare the array before the loop :

```
    char[] ascii = new char[str.length()];
    for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        ascii[i] = ch[i];
        System.out.println((int)ascii[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that, by this solution, the elements are not stored as array in the variable ascii, i have more later conversion to be done on the arrray ascii, so i dont use the line  char ascii = ch[i]; intentionally

Comment: can you tell me what was the mistake i was doing ? Clearly i was intializing array, what was the mistake ?

Comment: @penta You were attempting to initialize a char array (`char[]`) with a single `char`. That's not the way to initialize an array.

Comment: so you  are telling, char ascii[i]=ch[i]; was wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

when you declare ascii[i], you are trying to initialize a character array, but you are assigning it ch[i], which is a single character. Hence you get the error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to char[].`

As Eran said above, changing ascii variable from char array to character will resolve the issue.